# Deleting a line associated with a record using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure where I can delete all data pertaining to one name. This would include data in the Order table, Line_item table, and Customer table. Should I be sub-querying differently?[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETE_CUSTOMER -- Delete a customer
 @cus_id_arg DECIMAL, -- customer's ID.
 @first_name_arg VARCHAR(30), -- customer’s first name.
 @last_name_arg VARCHAR(40), -- customer's last name.
 @cust_balance_in_arg DECIMAL(12,2) -- customer's balance
AS -- This "AS" is required by the syntax of stored procedures.
BEGIN
 -- Insert the new customer with a 0 balance.
 DELETE FROM CUSTOMER

 WHERE order_id IN (SELECT order_id FROM customer_order where customer_id = @cus_id_arg);

END;
```

Comment: you need to delete from  `line_item` first then `customer_order` and last `customer`

Answer (score 1):

> **[`CASCADE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**
>
> Corresponding rows are deleted from the referencing table if that row is deleted from the parent table.

Add cascading constraints, and the delete will be easy

```
ALTER Customer_Order
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerID 
FOREIGN KEY(Customer_ID) REFERENCES (Customer_ID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER Line_Item
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Order_ID 
FOREIGN KEY(Order_ID) REFERENCES Customer_Order(Order_ID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Now, any row you delete it from `Customer` table will delete all corrrespending rows in `Customer_Order` table will be deleted, and the same for `Line_Item` table.

So you can write just `DELETE FROM Customer WHERE Customer_ID = @Customer_ID;`